# Postgres: Alter bigint column to inet

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres 11.1 and have a table that contains a column called ip for holding ipv4 and ipv6 values. (The ips do not contain any colons or dots).

I now want to alter this column to inet, since I realized the bigint is too small to hold ipv6 values.

I have tried the following, conversions:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN ip TYPE inet USING ip::inet;
```

but I get **ERROR: cannot cast type bigint to inet**

and

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN ip TYPE inet USING '0.0.0.0'::inet + cast(ip as bigint);
```

but I get **ERROR: operator does not exist: inet = character varying**

I have also tried converting the column from bigint to a varchar via:

```
alter table my_table alter column ip type varchar using ip::varchar;
```

only to get **ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = character varying**

Comment: Your second approach (using [`inet + bigint` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-net.html)) should [work just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=243dec590efdf483934bdfed93dc79d2), although the `cast` is unnecessary if your column had type  `bigint` before.

Comment: @Bergi hmm actually you're right, it appears that my problem isn't actually related to the actual altering the data set but possible because my POJO for this table is using a String for the ip still vs an equivlence to postfgres' 'inet' type.